# Python elif syntax error

Tags: python

Getting error:

```
ev3rest@EV3RESTs-MBP ~/Desktop> python telegram.py
  File "telegram.py", line 55
    elif message == '/start':
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Code:

```
if message == '/help':
send_respond ('/help respond message', from_id)
elif message == '/start':
    send_respond ('/help - Show available commands list', from_id)
elif message == 'Привет':
    send_respond ('Приветики!', from_id)
```

No idea how to fix it, i checked tabs, but that does not work :/

Comment: indent error in python indentation is a must

Comment: The code you posted is missing an indentation in line 2( the first send_respond). With the indentation added there I manage to run the code in python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elif syntax error in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25390661/elif-syntax-error-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Indent this one step backwards:

```
if message == '/help':
    send_respond ('/help respond message', from_id)  #<------------------HERE
```

Comment: but this one has no no errors. I used if and else statements later, there were no mistakes, but after adding one more var and changing else & if to elif it said there is a mistake in 
    elif message == '/start':
       ^

Comment: Python works through indentation, it defines scopes through indentaion. If you screw up indentaion at any level you'll get error nearby.